# Cannot access :development or :production credentials with [Rails.env]

Tags: amazon-s3, credentials, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am upgrading an app to Rails 5.2.0 and trying to create the `credentials.yml.enc` file so I can access a different `:aws` bucket for both `:development` and `:production` environments.

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336).

My credentials.yml.enc

```
development:
  aws:
    access_key_id: 123dev
    secret_access_key: 345dev
    bucket: development_bucket

production:
  aws:
    access_key_id: 123pr
    secret_access_key: 345pr
    bucket: production_bucket

aws:
  access_key_id: long_hexidecimal_string
  secret_access_key: longer_hexidecimal_string
```

In console, if I type `Rails.application.credentials[:aws][:access_key_id]` then I get the expected output: `long_hexidecimal_string`

But when I type `Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env][:aws][:access_key_id]` I get this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method []' for nil:NilClass`

Testing to see if problem is in the yml file, I tried this and got the expected result:

```
irb(main):015:0> Rails.application.credentials[:development][:aws][:access_key_id]
=> "123dev"
```

I think the problem is `[Rails.env]` yields `["development"]`, not `[:development]`.  Is there an easy way to symbolize the the `[Rails.env]` output?  I'm hoping for `[Rails.env.symbolize!]` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have spent more time googling rather than typing up this question.

```
irb(main):016:0> Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:aws][:access_key_id]
=> "123dev"
```

I hope this helps someone one day!